# Do users need to buy non-consumable in-app purchase twice for universal iOS apps?

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store, ios-universal-app

I'm working on an iOS 8 app and saw that it's possible to release an *universal* app for iPhone and iPad.
If you use non-consumable in-app purchases for an universal app, do users need to buy them only once and can use them on both devices or do they need to purchase them for iPhone and iPad?

Comment: make sure to implement "restore in-app" feature within your app

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Non-consumable products are purchased once by users and do not expire or decrease with use. For example, new race tracks for a game could be implemented as non-consumable products.

Means: If you used same iTune account credential then you can download as free.

[Apple Developer](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/CreatingInAppPurchaseProducts.html)